# Rabbitmq-server startup error in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install rabbitmq-server in ubuntu 12.04 and I am getting the following error

```
Setting up rabbitmq-server (2.8.7-1) ... 
* Starting message broker rabbitmq-server 
* FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err} ...fail! 
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed. 
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure): subprocess 
installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

When I checked startup err file it has only one line start failed

Answer (score 0):

Try a `dpkg-reconfigure rabbitmq-server` (or whatever the specific package name happens to be).  It appears the install partially failed.  If this doesn't work, you may need to do an `apt-get remove rabbitmq-server; apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

Pay close attention to the output.  If you don't want to do this, check the logfiles in /var/log/apt/ for any prior errors when you first installed rabbit.